# Get SQS message from a priority queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have 3 SQS queues:

- HighPQueue1
- MediumPQueue2
- LowPQueue3

Messages are inserted in the queue based on the API gateway REST API call. If the message is of high priority, it goes to HighPQueue1. If the message is medium, it goes to MediumPQueue2. If the message is low, it goes to LowPQueue3.

The messages from these 3 queues has to be read in priority order. How can I do that using AWS?

I have thought about creating a Lambda and then checking if message is available first in HighPQueue1, then in MediumPQueue2 and then in LowPQueue3. Would that be the right approach?

I have to trigger AWS step functions for each SQS message depending on the priority. I want to limit to 10 concurrent requests for my AWS step functions at any given point in time.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to trigger AWS step functions for each lambda call"? How is the Lambda being triggered? What is it doing?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I meant that for each SQS message, I need to trigger AWS step function.

Comment: @dang , you need an Event Source Mapping:  Take a look here: https://bitesizedserverless.com/bite/implement-the-priority-queue-pattern-with-sqs-and-lambda/#how-to-build-priority-queues-for-lambda-check-the-priority-queue-for-messages

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the lambda integration for this, but you could still use lambda if you want to start a new invocation every so often. I think what you are suggesting for the pattern is correct (check high, then medium, then low). Here are some things to keep in mind.

1. Make sure when you are checking the medium and low queues that you only request one message at a time if it's important that the high queue messages are processed quickly.
2. If you process any message you start over. In other words don't make the mistake of processing a high item and then checking the medium queue. Always start over.
3. Lambda may not be your best option if you are polling queues. You'll effectively have lambda compute running all the time. That still may be okay if this is the only workload running and you are staying within, or close to within, the free tier.
4. Consider handling multiple requests at the same time. Is there something in your downstream infrastructure that limits you to processing one message at a time? If not, I would skip this model entirely and go with one queue backed by lambda and running processes in parallel when multiple come in.

Comment: I have to trigger AWS step functions for each lambda call. I have a limit of 10 concurrent requests for my AWS step functions at any given point in time. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I would add that information to your question so that answers can be framed accordingly. That very much changes the model of how you might achieve this.

Comment: Added that info.